# .NET NpgSQL convert group array_agg and unnest SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I try to convert this (PostgreSQL) SQL to LINQ or to C# query expression, but without success.

Can anyone help me?

```
select apps.*, array_agg(pr) as permissions
from
    apps,
    assigned_roles,
    roles,
    unnest(roles.permissions) as pr
where
    (
        (assigned_roles.app_id is null and assigned_roles.org_id is null)
        or
        (apps.org_id = assigned_roles.org_id and apps.app_id is null)
        or
        (apps.org_id is null and apps.app_id = assigned_roles.app_id)
    ) 
    and 
    (
        roles.role_id = assigned_roles.role_id
        and
        assigned_roles.account_id = @p0
        and
        apps.org_id = @p1
        and
        roles.permissions @> ARRAY[@p2]::text[]
        and
        apps.deleted is null
    )
group by apps.app_id
order by apps.name
limit 100
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Someone once told me that if it is to complex to figure out in LINQ it probably should stay in SQL. In those complex scenario's I also believe SQL is still more readable then LINQ. Although this doesn't really solve your problem and im not sure what the exact requirements are, it's definitely a train of thought :D

Comment: Did you try the linq method Cast<type>()

Comment: As I know, currently it is only possible in `linq2db`. EF will not help in replacing SQL by LINQ in such cases.